# What is the best way to document a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database

Mainly, what is the best tool for the schema and tables relations visualization?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try out [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/)

[image]

Comment: I'm going to give it a try. Thanks a lot.